# Installing CouchDB 2.0.0 on Debian 8.6 fails

Tags: compiler-errors, installation, couchdb

I am unable to install CouchDB 2.0.0 on Debian 8.6. After downloading the source archive and calling `./configure` I tried to compile the source using `make release`.

However I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Unable to generate spec: read file info /usr/lib/erlang/man/man3/cerfcl.3.gz failed
ERROR: Unexpected error: rebar_abort
ERROR: generate failed while processing /home/debian/apache-couchdb-2.0.0/rel: rebar_abort
```

The dependencies should be satisfied as I installed the required packages as stated in the [docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/install/unix.html#dependencies).

Any suggestions about how to fix this error? I tried to delete the `cerfcl*` files from the `man/man3` directory by

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/erlang/man/man3/cerfcl/cerfcl*
```

without any success.

Answer (score 0):

Missing man pages of CERF

```
aptitude install libcerf-doc
```